# Nagios check_http failing with 404 on certain address

Tags: http-status-code-404, nagios

I have built 2 nagios servers this week. The first was just a proof of concept, and tonight I built the prod one.  I followed the exact same instructions on both, and migrated my existing configuration over to the new server tonight. Everything works perfect, except that some check_http checks are getting a 404 error, even though I can curl and wget the address.  Example:

```
./check_http -I 127.0.0.1 -u http://11.210.1.18:8001/alphaweb/login.html
HTTP WARNING: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found - 528 bytes in 0.000 second response time |time=0.000418s;;;0.000000 size=528B;;;0
```

I can curl this address with no problem.  But the following succeeds:

```
./check_http -I 127.0.0.1 -u http://11.210.1.16:7001
HTTP OK: HTTP/1.1 200 OK - 288 bytes in 0.001 second response time |time=0.000698s;;;0.000000 size=288B;;;0
```

Both of these checks work perfectly on an almost identical server, any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure why you have the -I as 127.0.0.1 (localhost) and the -u pointing to another site.   Can you add -v flag and post the output?

Answer (score 0):

Good thing is, that you receive some http status code, even 404 is good one, because you somehow interact with web server.

## check log files on target web servers

Assuming you have access to the target web server I would recommend you to check log files.

Both requests, even the one with 404 status code, shall be seen there. And here can come a surprise, you might find, that while your check is getting some response, your log files is not showing any log record about it. In such a case I would suspect some proxy or iptables in the way.

## doublecheck spelling of your calls

But the cause could be much simpler - small mistake in your command causing significant difference.